# Error using bcrypt compare function

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, bcrypt

I get this error when trying to compare password with `bcrypt`
**Error:** `Error: data and hash arguments required`

This is my code

```
//compare password
        bcrypt.compare(req.param('password'), user.encryptedPassword, function(err, valid) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            //if password doesn't match
            if (!valid) {
                var usernamePasswordMismatchError = [{name: 'usernamePasswordMismatch', message: 'Invalid Password'}]
                req.session.flash = {
                    err: usernamePasswordMismatchError
                }
                res.redirect('/session/new');
                return;
            }

            //log user in
            req.session.authenticated = true;
            req.session.User = user;

            //redirect user to profile page
            res.redirect('/user/show/'+ user.id);
        });
```

This is my schema setup

```
  module.exports = {
   attributes: {

     name: {
       type: 'string',
       required: true
     },
     email: {
       type: 'string',
       email: true,
       required: true,
       unique: true
     },
     phone: {
       type: 'string',
       required: true
     },
     encryptedPassword: {
       type: 'string'
     },

     toJSON: function() {
       var obj = this.toObject();
       delete obj.password;
       delete obj.encryptedPassword;
       delete obj._csrf;
       return obj;
    }

   },
  connection:'mongodb'
 };
```

Please what am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the code look like for generating the password hash?

Comment: the password hash is done in the schema

Comment: What do you mean "done in the schema". Which code generates it? Somewhere you need to generate it using `bcrypt` so you can compare the hash later.

Comment: please can u give me an example.....just learning sails of recent

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling the bcrypt.compare() function, you need to make sure you supply both the password and the hashed password. So put a print there and see what are you missing.

Case 1: req.param('password') is empty for some reason (the field name in your html form may have a typo)

Case 2: user.encryptedPassword is empty. For this case the reason might be that you don't encrypt your password when creating/updating your user record. In order to make sure you do, open your database and after creating a new user check the record in the DB and see if your encryptedPassword is there. Here is an example how you can encrypt the password in time of creation/update:

In your User model you may have these functions:

```
beforeUpdate: function (values, next) {
    if (values.password) {
        bcrypt.hash(values.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            values.encryptedPassword = hash;
            next();
        });
    }
},

beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
    bcrypt.hash(values.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        values.encryptedPassword = hash;
        next();
    });
}
```

Note this line:

```
values.encryptedPassword = hash;
```

Since you don't have a password attribute in the schema, the values.password that is supplied will not be saved anywhere. The other thing in your case may be that you don't set encryptedPassword anywhere. So the other approach is to alter your schema and rename encryptedPassword to simple password and then replace

```
values.encryptedPassword = hash;
```

with

```
values.password = hash;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the scope of your compare function but it looks like either or both of your input params to bcrypt.compare is either empty or null.
(compare function requires both input params to be non-null and non-empty)

Try logging your req.param('password') and user.encryptedPassword to further debug your issue.

Ref: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js